# Distance beetwen primes

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

How to prove that distance between two neighboring primes can be arbitrarily large?
Thanks for help,
John

Comment: You need to provide more information.  Why do you think the statement is true?  Do you have any idea how a proof might go?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: after $n!+1$ there can be no primes until ...

Answer (score 2):

Here is a lazy way, although probably not the most elementary one. Look at the [prime counting function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function) $\pi(x)$. If gaps between neighbouring primes were bounded by some number $N$, then we would have $\pi(x) \geq x / (100N)$. On the other hand, we have Tchebyshev's inequality $\pi(x) \leq C x / \ln x$ for some positive $C$. Contradiction. Of course, we still need to prove Tchebyshev's inequality, but that can be found in standard texts...

Comment: Hi, I know Tchebyshev inequality :) Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Consider a large $p$,

$(p-1)! \equiv -1 \pmod p$ (Wilson's theorem).

$(p-1)!+1 \equiv 0 \pmod p$

$(p-1)+2 \equiv 0 \pmod 2$.

.

.

.

$(p-1)!+(p-1) \equiv 0 \pmod{p-1}$.